# How can I alter the order of dataframes and then merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes like so:

```
[
               0
 Vessel.1     SOV
 Utilization 0.81,
                0    1
 Vessel.1      DC  SOV
 Utilization 0.37 0.47,
                0    1    2
 Vessel.1      DC   DC  SOV
 Utilization 0.37 0.04 0.46,
                0    1    2    3
 Vessel.1      DC   DC   DC  SOV
 Utilization 0.37 0.04 0.03 0.44
]
```

And I would like to convert this to a dataframe which looks like:

```
  SOV     DC 1    DC 2    DC 3
0 0.81    nan     nan     nan
1 0.47    0.37    nan     nan
2 0.46    0.37    0.04    nan
3 0.44    0.37    0.04    0.03
```

I have tried playing around with merging, concatenating etc but I cant quite get it to work.

Edit:
Here is a runnable code for the last dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["DC", "DC", "DC", "SOV"],
                   [0.37, 0.04, 0.03, 0.45]])
df.index = ["Vessel.1", "Utilization"]
```

Comment: you could add a column to each and call it say "rank" and then concat the dataframes and order by rank?

Comment: Can you please post one of the DataFrames as code so we can reproduce the structure? Not sure if you have multi-level headings or?

Comment: @not_speshal I have modified my question with an example dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do some convert function

```
def cvt(x):
    x = x.T.set_index('Vessel.1')
    x.index = x.index + x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str)
    return x
out = pd.concat([ cvt(x) for x in l ],axis=1).T
Out[178]: 
             SOV0   DC0   DC1   DC2
Utilization  0.81   NaN   NaN   NaN
Utilization  0.47  0.37   NaN   NaN
Utilization  0.46  0.37  0.04   NaN
Utilization  0.44  0.37  0.04  0.03
```